# Apache: Use RewriteRule as proxy of sort

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to host my front-end on some shared hosting solution, but face some issues with that.
*Note: This is **not** supposed to be the definitive hosting solution, but I'd be able to manually test things more accuratetly that way.*

My front-end needs to access some API located on a different server. For convenience (authentication and the likes), I'd like to proxy my API requests to the back-end server.
However, being in a shared hosting environment restricts my options :

- I cannot modify the `VirtualHost` configuration
- `mod_proxy` seems to be disabled, so no `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassReverse` allowed
- `mod_rewrite` seems to be enabled

I thought about using
`RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1`
as a proxy of sorts, but I'm afraid this will not work as intended...

I'm open to any suggestions and "Do not do this!"

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a proxy using Apache without mod_proxy. The `P` flag that can be used with mod_rewrite (on the `RewriteRule` directive) uses mod_proxy.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
> ```

Presumably, you are limited to `.htaccess`, in which case the above `RewriteRule` *pattern* (with a slash prefix) would never match anyway, so the directive wouldn't do anything. However, even after correcting the *pattern*, when you specify an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* it will implicitly trigger an external 302 redirect (unless the request is sent through mod_proxy) - which I gather is not what you require.

I can only suggest that you perhaps manage this "proxy" with your server-side code instead. For instance, you could potentially use CURL to "proxy" the request?

Comment: Well, that's what I thought... Thanks for answering anyway :)